# Whatsapp send button

Tags: iphone, ios4, xamarin.ios, ios5

Currently I am building an application which has a bar just like the whatsapp one. You are able to fill in some text here and hit send.

Now I am wondering.. how did Whatsapp create this button? Because I'm trying to do it programmatically but I'm not able to work around some stuff.
Does whatsapp just use an image for this? Because their text on the button is text and not an image..

I'm hope someone can help me out with this. Currently I am using MonoTouch, but a native C example will do of course!

[image: button]

Comment: You need to put a link of the whatsapp or a screenshot,so that somebody can get an idea.

Comment: Alright, I added the screenshot. Thanks :-)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright. It is a UIButton with custom type. You need to put image as background of a UIButton and set its type as custom. Hope that will help you buddy.

Comment: Sarah, thanks alot for your response and I will try that. The image you're talking about is just the rounded blue thingy as a transparent png image? Do I need to include the shadows + the text inside the button too? Thanks for your quick response missy!

Comment: Well...tell me if it's giving click event on the blue colored part only or on the gray part too??

Comment: Give me a second and I'll integrate my background with it. I'll let you know in a bit.

Comment: It also highlights the gray stuff Sarah, but the whatsapp button does that too so that's not an issue. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. Didn't think the solution was that easy. Wished I had your help much sooner :P

Comment: I did that, thanks again. By the way you're able to set different images for different states. So if you really don't want the gray to highlight when you click it, it's possible to give a different image when highlighted.

Comment: yes it is possible. Check the properties for diff states of unbutton like selected and all.